# Constant function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

(a) Use the derivative to prove that the function

$$F(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^{1/x} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$
is constant in the interval $(0, +\infty)$.

(b) Determine the constant value of the function in part (a) and then interpret (a) as a
identity involving the arctangent function.

I thought about using the fundamental theorem of calculus to calculate the derivative and prove that it is equal to $0$, but the result was not necessarily $0$. For letter (b) I have no idea, honestly. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please show your work. We can point out why you didn't get $0$ for (a) if you show your work.

Comment: I considered $$F'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1/x)^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^ 2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=1$$

Comment: The second integral needs you to also differentiate the 1/x in the upper limit. This is basically the chain rule, although it's sometimes called the Liebniz rule in this context.

Comment: Regarding question (b). Use the substitution $t = tan(u)$.

Comment: $$\int_0^{1/x} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}\overset{t=\frac1s}{=}\int_x^\infty\frac{ds}{1+s^2}\,\Rightarrow\,F(x)=\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: Similar to @Svyatoslav but $t\mapsto 1/t$ for the first integral gives
$$F(x)=\int_{1/x}^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt+\int_0^{1/x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt$$
which is constant.

Answer (score 0):

**(a)**
We have with the help of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) :
$$
F'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{1+1/x^2} = 0
$$
$\Rightarrow$ $F$ is constant function.

**(b)**
Let's choose $x = 1$ in order to kill the first integral, hence :
$$
F(x) = F(1) = \left.\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2} = \arctan(t)\right|_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{4} - 0 = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$